# pandas: map color argument by multidict

Tags: pandas, dictionary

I would like to map a color to each row in the dataframe as a function of two columns. It would be much easier with just one column as argument. But how can I achieve this with two columns ?

What I have done so far:

```
a = np.random.rand(3,10)
i = [[30,10], [10, 30], [60, 60]]
names = ['a', 'b']
index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(i, names = names)
df = pd.DataFrame(a, index=index).reset_index()

c1 = plt.cm.Greens(np.linspace(0.2,0.8,3))
c2 = plt.cm.Blues(np.linspace(0.2,0.8,3))
#c3 = plt.cm.Reds(np.linspace(0.2,0.8,3))

color = np.vstack((c1,c2))
a = df.a.sort_values().values
b = df.b.sort_values().values

mapping = dict()
for i in range(len(a)):
    mapping[a[i]] = {}
    for ii in range(len(b)):
        mapping[a[i]][b[ii]] = color[i+ii]
```

Maybe something similar to `df['color'] = df.apply(lamda x: mapping[x.a][x.b])` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you answered your own question. Apply can happen across the rows by changing the axis argument to 1. `df['color'] = df.apply(lambda x: mapping[x.a][x.b], axis =1)`